# HTML | Mobile and CSS media types

Tags: css, mobile, types, media

Below are my stylesheets for my mobile site:

```
<META name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
<META name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px)" href="css/smartmobile.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="css/smartmobile.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="handheld" href="css/mobile.css" />
```

I loaded the page in an iPhone and it looks like it's supposed to. However when I load the page in a Blackberry it doesn't use the "handhled" one but rather tries to use the other stylesheets. Anyone have any thoughts to why this happening?

Comment: is the "mobile view" setting off?

Comment: I am not sure. I am working with strictly defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes most phones even more so the older ones will simply ignore the "media" type and I would suggest using some from of server side detection if you *need* the css to be different on different phone types.

Comment: Then sadly your solution is lacking and you *are* going to have devices that simply don't work well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider media queries (as you've done for iPhone) instead of media types. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/ Many devices don't support the `handheld` media type.

Comment: And you think they support media queries? I think not.

Comment: Lots of devices support media queries.

Comment: I went with Javascript and the <noscript> tag for the Blackberry.

Comment: @stenphenhay Do you have stats on that or are you basing this on web browsers?